# RingCentral call management

Tags: javascript, c#, ringcentral

When someone calls I am able to get the call ID but I can not find a way to put the call on hold. I do not mean making a VOIP client I want to control calls that go to peoples phones. I want to do things like put calls on hold take them off hold and transfer them to others. I know that the system can do that because there are codes you can enter into your touch tone while in a call but I am not sure how or if the API can do this.

Ideally I can do this in C# but Javascript or any other language that can do it will also work if C# can not for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the only way to do programmatic call control as you mention is via the RingCentral WebRTC API which has call control and DTMF tone support. You can find more information on this in the documentation for the RingCentral WebRTC JavaScript SDK:

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone

To do this without WebRTC, a separate call control API is needed. This isn't available yet, but you can make a request for this on the RingCentral developer community:

https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com/

Comment: When you say call control do you mean controlling a call that is for example a ring out / a incoming call that was answered on a real phone or do you mean making a voip client?

Comment: In this case, I mean a call being handled by a web client, such as an outgoing call made using the WebRTC SDK or an incoming call answered using the WebRTC SDK. Support for hard phones is being considered, but not currently available.